# Create a box in HTML and align it left or right inside a normal text

Tags: html

Let’s say I have a normal text in a paragraph (*<p>...</p>*). Now I want to place a box with, for example, ads or additional information somewhere in the text to the right or left. It should *not* be above or below the text; the text should align itself around the box.

How would I do this? I tried with span and div, but I failed so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "align itself around the box"?  Can you lay it out in ascii art, or upload an image so we can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<div>` with `float` CSS property.

```
<p>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px; float: right"></div>
    XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX 
    XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX 
    XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX 
    XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX 
    XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX 
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, that comes close, I am going to experiment with this! Thanks so far.

Comment: add margin attribute as well, for nice spacing

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with HTML alone but with CSS you can float a child element to one side.

http://jsfiddle.net/9A2vB/